# Azure : Client to Server unattended secure authentication

Tags: authentication, security, server, client

I have a web app deployed on Azure, that listens for incoming POST authenticated requests using the EasyAuth module.

The client is a JS app (browser extension) that runs as a background process and needs to send authenticated POST requests to the server. No user interaction allowed.

Currently I use a hardcoded client-id/secret within the client app to retrieve the OAUTH2 token to authenticate my POST queries.

However i was wondering if there wasn't a better approach than this to make the communication a little more secure ?

If that is not possible what would you recommend as a best practice to try and obfuscate as much as possible the secret / certificate used to authenticate the client against the server ?

The main concern here is that a malicious user should not be able to retrieve the credentials that serve to generate a token. He may retrieve a token but shouldn't be able to generate one.

My use case is extremely similar to that of which is employed by MDM providers to secure their client - server communication.